# Confidence that a distribution is uniform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, confidence-interval

I run a distributed software making rounds.
Each round has a 35% probability of success.
I've been monitoring it for quite some time, and I have the intuition that the successes are happening in "packs", example 3 successes in a row then 7 fails, etc etc...

I already have a significant amount of repetitions.
What metric can I use to verify if the successes tends to make "packs" or if it was a wrong impression?

Comment: Maybe the Wald-Wolfowitz test?

Comment: ty this is exactly what I was looking for